# Symfony Doctrine error

Tags: symfony

i am following a tutorial about symfony. im trying to create an entity by console.

The thing is when i name it some errors come up.

> root@asus-K53SD:/opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony# php bin/console >doctrine:generate:entity
>
> Welcome to the Doctrine2 entity generator
>
> This command helps you generate Doctrine2 entities.
>
> First, you need to give the entity name you want to generate.
>   You must use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post.
>
> The Entity shortcut name: AppBundle:todo
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
>    An exception occured in driver: could not find driver
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>    could not find driver
>
> [PDOException]
>   could not find driver

anyone knows how can i fix this?

Here is the the repository where i am working.
https://bitbucket.org/mariogarciait/symfony/src

thanks

EDITING

I couldnt find a solution to this problem. I had always on the top of my head that the problem was something related with the SO (linux). What i've done is to buy a pc with window (i dont want it in my lovely laptop hehe) and i hadnt that problem anymore.

Comment: The error is pretty clear :  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver. What database are you using? MySQL? If so, have you installed the php-mysql libraries?

Comment: @ChuckNorris I am using MySQL with Xampp. i believe it is installed properly as i have others projects with database access.

Comment: Can you show your `parameters.yml` and your `config.yml` with Doctrine section please?

Comment: @AlvinBunk here is a link to the whole code
https://bitbucket.org/mariogarciait/symfony/

Comment: Hi Zenit. I think you included the wrong link, that link doesn't show your code. Also, it's best to simply `edit` your post and include the config, since if it gets answered, it will help other users.

Comment: Hi @AlvinBunk
i edited it. thanks for letting me know.
the file parameters.yml is in
https://bitbucket.org/mariogarciait/symfony/src/d327aacae5b589db1cdd165da3b17ff3eb5605fe/app/config/parameters.yml.dist?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

and config.yml

https://bitbucket.org/mariogarciait/symfony/src/d327aacae5b589db1cdd165da3b17ff3eb5605fe/app/config/config.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: We need to see the `parameters.yml` not the `parameters.yml.dist`!

Comment: Apology. For some reason that file was ignored.

https://bitbucket.org/mariogarciait/symfony/src/95fcce75e1b169f94e1bdb5683f9493ed7d42448/app/config/parameters.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Sometimes these error simply means a default value is required to be set in one of the columns in the table which you are trying to insert into. But first, i suggest you check and consider updating doctrine if its not.